# how to import text to lucidchart entity relationship diagram

Tags: lucidchart

I have extensive amount of csv files and i parsed and get a filenames and column names to import any ER diagram tool. But when lucidchar expect query result. If i have example outcome of query to import entity relationship. I can arrange my format according to that and import to the lucidchart. Anyone has a expected format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You insert the output of your query, for example if you use MySQL

```
SELECT 'mysql' dbms,t.TABLE_SCHEMA,t.TABLE_NAME,c.COLUMN_NAME,c.ORDINAL_POSITION,c.DATA_TYPE,c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,n.CONSTRAINT_TYPE,k.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA,k.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,k.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c ON t.TABLE_SCHEMA=c.TABLE_SCHEMA AND t.TABLE_NAME=c.TABLE_NAME LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE k ON c.TABLE_SCHEMA=k.TABLE_SCHEMA AND c.TABLE_NAME=k.TABLE_NAME AND c.COLUMN_NAME=k.COLUMN_NAME LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS n ON k.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA=n.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA AND k.CONSTRAINT_NAME=n.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND k.TABLE_SCHEMA=n.TABLE_SCHEMA AND k.TABLE_NAME=n.TABLE_NAME WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN('INFORMATION_SCHEMA','mysql');
```