# Importing CSV to LucidChart to create ERD diagram

Tags: csv, erd, lucidchart

Referencing older question - [Importing CSV to LucidChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51263626/how-to-import-text-to-lucidchart-entity-relationship-diagram). My issue is similar but database I'm getting my schema from is not a db type listed on LucidChart, its coming from databricks, not sure if that'd have any impact. Regardless I've followed the suggested query structure from LucidChart to get metadata for my schema and exported to CSV, but when I try uploading to LucidChart I get an error message unable to parse but no indication what is the source of the error.

Has any one run into this issue? is it a question of formatting output query (i.e. double-quotes around each value in the CSV)

Example of (raw) CSV used for import to LucidChart; `cat`-ed first few lines

```
databricks,ds_table,treasury,pl_sections
databricks,ds_table,treasury,orders
databricks,ds_table,treasury_teradata,pl_subscriptions
```

Expected no issues but getting a parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same error when trying to import tables from snowflake. If you change the values of the `dbms` column from `databricks` to one of the referenced databases e.g. `mysql` then it will import correctly.

My output from snowflake had the exact naming as `mysql` and it imported without issue once I changed it.